# Is the DOM oninput event supported in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom

This [oninput Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) documentation explains:

> The oninput event occurs when an element gets user input.
>
> This event occurs when the value of an  or  element
> is changed.
>
> Tip: This event is similar to the onchange event. The difference is
> that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an
> element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses
> focus, after the content has been changed. The other difference is
> that the onchange event also works on  elements.

I'd like to use that from this LWC code:

```
<lightning-input-field
    ...
    oninput={handleOnInput}
    ...
></lightning-input-field>
```

but the handle function never gets called, at least in my code.

Should this work? Is there some LWC documentation that explains which DOM events are supported?

Comment: Hey Keith, AFAIK there are no registerable event handlers, certainly none in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation). That said the documentation has an example in "Lookup Fields" that shows the use of what looks to be both "success" and "change" events.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation)

> The native HTML  element provides two events,
> input and change. The lightning-input component provides two custom
> events, change, and commit.
>
> The component's change event behaves the same as the native input and
> change events together. It fires whenever you change the input value,
> as the  element's input event does. It also fires when you
> finish changing the input, as the  element's change event does.
>
> The component's commit event fires only when you finish changing the
> input, which is the same behavior as the HTML  element's change
> event.
>
> The component doesn't provide an input event because the behavior is
> provided in the change event.
>
> To summarize, the component's change event is equivalent to the input
> and change events of the  element. The component's commit event
> is equivalent to the change event of the  element.

So you should use `onchange` for normal input fields and `oncommit` for search types

```
<lightning-input label="My input" onchange={handler}></lightning-input>
```

if the `change` event doesn't suit the need, we can always switch to a standard HTML input element

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex">My input</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow">
        <input type="text" oninput={handler} class="slds-input" value={value}>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Anmol; the change event fires at a different time so not suitable for what I want.

Comment: Got it! in that case, I think standard HTML input element is always an option :)

Comment: Also, this is the lightning-input not lightning-input-field...

Comment: (This does not answer the question)